# Vim: How to install plugin for a particular filetype?

Tags: vim

Yesterday I came across [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) plugin which provides auto-completion for python. I installed the plugin using pathogen by placing it in `bundle` directory and it is working fine.

Now, as I have mentioned that this plugin is only for `filetype: python` so I want  to load it only when I open files with `.py` extensions and not when I open other files like `.java, .perl, .sh`.

So, how can this be achieved.

I am a vim beginner/noob but I googled before asking and found that this can be achieved using `vim ftplugin` but I have no idea whatsoever where to place which file.

Comment: As the writer of jedi and jedi-vim I ask you: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing about plugins. Probably it is fine with jedi-vim, but I have a couple of really simple plugins which are loaded independently of the file type. But when I get more complex plugin solution for a specific file type(for example jedi-viim) I would like to have only it loaded and prevent the simple plugins from messing around. What I need is more like blacklist of file types per plugin, not a whitelist.

Answer (score 3):

There are plugin managers for Vim that do this

For your example in [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug).

```
Plug 'davidhalter/jedi-vim', {'for': 'python'}
```

where the string is the author/name of the github repository. All scripts from vim.org are also rehosted on github via [vim-scripts.org](http://vim-scripts.org/) under the user [vim-scripts](https://github.com/vim-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when wanting to conditionally load `jedi-vim` and using the plugin manager `Vundle`. Now, after a little research I found out that `Vundle` will load all of its packages/plugins an run time, and there wasn't much I could do about it.

However, `jedi-vim` has the possibility of being automatically loaded or not. So I decided to have `jedi-vim` option set to zero (not loaded automatically) in my `~/.vimrc` set to one on my `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` file.

This option is:

`" supposing this is the .vim/ftplugin/python.vim file 
let g:jedi#auto_initialization = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Especially for complex plugins, the plugin must be written in a way that minimizes its effects on other filetypes. You didn't state why you want to limit the plugin's application to Python files (as long as it doesn't install global mappings that interfere with other mappings, you'd normally not care), but after finding an [issue about slow loading time](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/7), I suspect it's that.

Until the plugin author provides a fix, you can try moving the `plugin/jedi.vim` file (and the corresponding `jedi_vim.py`) one directory up, so that it isn't sourced automatically when Vim starts. When you want to use the plugin, load it via `:runtime jedi.vim`. Maybe you can even move the files into the `ftplugin/` folder; they would then be automatically sourced when a Python file is edited; try it out.

Alternatively, you could completely separate the `.vim` directories for Python and other development, and use two different aliases to start `vim-with-python` vs. plain vim:

```
alias vim-with-python='vim --cmd "set rtp^=~/.vim-with-python" --cmd "set rtp+=~/.vim-with-python/after"'
```

Comment: By one directory up you mean moving it from `bundle/jedi-vim/plugin` to `bundle/jedi-vim` b'coz this didn't worked. it showed some errors saying `undefined variable ...`

Comment: Yes, actually, any directory outside `plugin/` is fine, because only those are sourced on startup. But as I said, for complex plugins spread over many files, this may not be so easy; you'd have to reverse-engineer the dependency structure and calling sequence.

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581218/vim-how-to-run-load-certain-plugins-on-certain-filetypes